# SSIS Lookup Transformation Issue - New Column Inserting Correctly, but Edits Redirected to No Match Output

Tags: ssis

My source data is an Excel CSV file.
I'm doing it for one single table.
Data Flow Steps:

I use a Data Conversion transformation after reading the CSV file.
A Lookup transformation is employed to check for matches in the destination table based on a unique identifier.
Lookup and Condition Split:

If a match is found in the Lookup, I direct the flow through a Condition Split.
In the Condition Split, I check if the data is not null with respect to an ID column.
If it's not null, I use an OLE DB Command to update the record.
If there's no match in the Lookup, the flow goes to the "No Match Output," and the data is directly inserted into the destination using an OLE DB Destination.
Problem:

When I add a new column, the SSIS package works as expected, and the new data is inserted correctly.
However, when I edit existing data, the Lookup seems to categorize it as "No Match," and the edited data is inserted as new instead of updating the existing record.

I've verified that the key columns in the Lookup match the columns I'm using for matching.
The conditions in the Condition Split are correctly set for the "Match Output" and "No Match Output."
The data types in the source, Lookup, and destination are consistent.

Comment: Maybe check that your source (SSIS object) is still accurate. The extra column may be throwing off your initial read into fields.